# Hide UIView starting from Bottom on Scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` and I would like to hide the `UIView` above it as the user scrolls down. Currently, scrolling hides the `UIView` from top-to-bottom.

How can I hide the `UIView` from **bottom-to-top** (as in the example below):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please show the code you use to cover the `UIView` from top to bottom, it should be easy to modify to do it from bottom to top.

Comment: @Arkku I just have the UIView placed above the TableViewCells in Storyboard. The UIView gets scrolled up first.

Comment: Well, in that case the issue is that it isn't getting scrolled up; in your screenshots the "Check-in Friday" text is in the same place for all scroll positions. If you're using auto layout, create constraints to set the height of the `UIView` constant, width to equal the parent view's, and bottom to distance 0 from the top of the topmost seed.

Comment: @Arkku Yes, the issue isn't that it isn't getting scrolled up. The issue is that the `UIView` gets scrolled up from the top first. I'd like the bottom of the `UIView` to disappear first (the same way as shown in the images).

Comment: Wait, those images are _not_ what you have currently but what you want to have?

Comment: @Arkku those images are what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but possibly the easiest way to do it:

In the storyboard, put the `UIView` at the top (let's call it the “top bar”) *outside* the scrollview, and arrange it so that it is *behind* the scrollview. Make sure it is of fixed height and position at the top of the screen (width should vary according to width of the screen).

Then in the place where you used to have the `UIView`, place a completely transparent view of equal size and disable user interaction for it. You can also put in a little gradient at the bottom of this view to fade over the top bar behind it (i.e., the gradient should be completely transparent at the top and the background colour of the top bar at the bottom). Your fixed-position top bar should now show through this transparent window which scrolls upwards and out of sight. The ugliness is that the scroll position indicator includes this transparent window.

Doing it “properly” requires you to set a class as the delegate of scrolling `tableView`, implement the `scrollViewDidScroll` method and inside that method adjust the auto layout constraints (or view positions if laying out manually) according to `scrollView.contentOffset.y`. The starting point of this option is also to have the top bar behind and outside of `tableView`, but instead of having the transparent view you would adjust the top edge position of `tableView`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to track the scroll direction. For example:

```
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    if (currentOffset.y > self.lastContentOffset.y) {
        // (Downward) Show my View
    } else {
        // (Upward) Hide My View
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = currentOffset;
}
```

Comment: Does tracking the scroll direction hide the UIView starting from the bottom?

Comment: Tracking your scroll, you get a start point for do whatever you want. For exapmple.. If it is scrolling `bottom-to-top`.. hide your `UIView` else show `UIView`

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to make the `UIView` hide starting from the bottom.

Comment: Do you want to animate this hiding? Is it?

Comment: No, I would like to hide the UIView *bottom-to-top* as the user scrolls down. Currently, my UIView hides *top-to-bottom*.

Comment: Currently I'm using storyboard with a `UIView` placed above the TableViewCell. It automatically hides the UIView from *top-to-bottom*.

Comment: Above TableViewCell? I cant figure out what you definely want. Maybe you are doing it completelly wrong. Looking for your image, I think that you have an `UIView` above `UITableview`. And if it scrolled to top, it should be hided. But `UIView` above `UITableViewCell`? I doest smell good.

Comment: Yes, the `UIView` is above the `UITableViewCell` and it hides on scroll. But I am trying to make it hide from the bottom to top (see images in question)